# Term to describe where the first word of a sentence rhymes with the last word of the same sentence?

Tags: poetry, terminology, rhythm

Is there an official term to describe a rhyming technique where the first word of a sentence rhymes with the last word of the same sentence?

For example, lines such as

> Brian almost got eaten by a lion

or

> Meet by the fields of wheat

where the rhymes essentially envelop the entire sentence.

Comment: Me think this is a question for English SE.

Comment: @DWKraus I think this is perfectly on-topic here, as per the [tag:terminology] tag. It *is* on-topic for English.SE as well, but that's not a reason to migrate it there.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is called an internal rhyme.
Here’s what I found on Wikipedia.

> In poetry, internal rhyme, or middle rhyme, is rhyme that occurs
> within a single line of verse, or between internal phrases across
> multiple lines. By contrast, rhyme between line endings is known as
> end rhyme.
>
> -[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rhyme)

Comment: Yes, this is internal rhyme.